Relativistic Doppler shift moving source in a circle
I am looking to understand the value for the relativistic doppler shift in the following scenario.
We have a source moving in a circular pattern around a center. Now, if the observer would be in the center of the circle, it would experience the transversal Doppler shift component (overall it would see a redshifted frequency compared to the source).
Question 1: What happens if the observer is outside the circle, what would be the frequency he would notice? (If the formula is a complicated integral, maybe what is the average observed frequency?)
Question 2: what if the observer is at a large distance from the source, so that the circle on which the source moves has an angular size that tends to zero?

Why would someone give negative rating to a question? Hope this doesn’t affect visibility.

Qt DVed because you mentioned 2 separate questions => "needs more focus" and asking for just "what happens" or "what if" is too generic... => care to mention a more specific question and problem statement?

Sorry if my questions caused any confusion. As I mentioned in the first paragraph, I want to know the value for the relativistic Doppler shift for the two scenarios described in my 2 questions. What is the frequency observed compared to the source frequency?

P.S. Downvotes only affect visibility once a question was downvoted -4 or worse, in which case they are hidden from the homepage.

Thank you for the clarification, good to know.
